# How can remove the right rail of the fandom

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to use Tampermonkey to remove the right rail of a page. Every page in the fandom.com wikis, contains a right rail, which is usually distracting me from focusing on the main content.

The element, according to DevTools looks like this:

```html
<div class="page has-right-rail">
  <main class="page__main" lang="en"> *content* </main>
  <aside class="page__right-rail">*content to be removed*</aside>
</div>
```

I usually delete it manually (it's the `<aside class="page__right-rail>...</aside>"` element).

[Here is an example page](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Guide:Getting_started) that has the thing. If possible, I'd like the script to work on `*something.*fandom.com/wiki/*something*`.

Here is the current version of my script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove Right Rail from Fandom
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*.fandom.com/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    document.querySelector('aside.page__right-rail').remove();

})();
```

Comment: See: [`@match` header](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_match) in the official Tampermonkey documentation, then `document.querySelector('aside.page__right-rail').remove()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Switched to @include http://* and it works, I'll look into narrowing it. 
It's working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now, do I delete the post? Can I mark it as completed myself?

Comment: Change `@match` to `http*://*.fandom.com/wiki/*`, so the script runs on the pages you want it to.

Comment: @JTMx you can [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)